# why is my onchange asp.net combo box not being called?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

i dont think my on change function is being called...why?

```
Public Sub selCurrentManuf_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles selCurrentManuf.SelectedIndexChanged
   Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('"+"oi"+"');</script>")
End Sub   

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="selCurrentManuf"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="selCurrentManuf_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `AutoPostBack="true"` to your control markup; assuming you want it to do the action immediately. Otheriwse the event won't fire until the form is submitted in some other way.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="selCurrentManuf" autopostback="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="selCurrentManuf_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: You are a genius! ive been at it for days!

Comment: @Beginner I showed that genius compliment to my co-workers, they still don't believe it. But glad I could help.